# Are there any Oracle Stored Procedure Accessor Generators for C++?

Tags: c++, oracle, plsql

I've been spending more and more time writing DB Wrappers for Oracle access. This seems to be quite generic procedure, and I was wondering is there already are code generators that generate access routes to Oracle PL/SQL Stored Procedures in C++?

I'm looking for a configurable generation tool that would be capable of managing connection and handle multiple threads if needed. I'm aware of OCI/OCCI and Oracle C++ extension, but I'm looking for a pure `self-contained C++ accessor generation tool`.

Any advice welcome.

Thank You!

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/74141/203968

Comment: OCCI is pretty good. I use it for a long time and it's really nice. It's tested on lots of servers, it's very fast and gives you much opportunities. I'd recommend that :) Also, the support is pretty good.

Comment: I'm specifically looking for a tool to generate accessors for PL/SQL procedures based on their headers and type information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might also want to have a look at:

- http://orclib.sourceforge.net
- http://otl.sourceforge.net/
- http://www.codeguru.com/cpp/data/mfc_database/oracle/article.php/c4305

Answer (score 1):

We use the SQLAPI (http://www.sqlapi.com/) for all of our C++ development w/ Oracle.  It I think is a more efficient wrapper for the OCI (though as another person pointed out, the OCCI is prety good).  Another advantage for the SQLAPI is that it also supports other database platforms.  We use it for MySQL as well and having that abstraction layer in between our application and database layers certainly simplifies things quite a bit.